# Possible to execute os level commands from a Google Packaged App? If so, what's the API?

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome-app

My apologies if this is a silly question, but I couldn't find the answer in my searching on google or on SO.  I'm trying to determine whether or not it is possible to call system level commands from a Google Chrome Packaged app.  For example, can I call the command interpreter (cmd) on the Windows OS from a packaged app?  And on OSX, can I execute any CLI command from the app?  Which Google Chrome API should I be looking into in order to accomplish this, and what are the security concerns that might arise from doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly from JavaScript and you can't do it with NaCL either.

Comment: Sounds like a definite "no".